# How to return a JSON list in the following format

Tags: javascript, json, bubble.io

I am using the bubble.io plugin builder. To return a response under bubble.io's api connector, all parameters returned must have the prefix "*p*". In the following case, this returns the correct results for an api call.

```
const options = {
    url: url
    ,method: method
    ,headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
const response = context.request(options);
    console.log(response);
    
/* 

The model we will use 
{
  "mins": 5,
  "price": "34823.91104827"
}

*/

var body = JSON.parse(response.body);

const {convert} = require('json-to-bubble-object');
    
let returnlist = []
returnlist.push(     {
  "_p_mins": body.mins.toString(),
  "_p_price": body.price,
  "_p_api_response": JSON.stringify(convert(body))
 
})
 
    return {
        "result": returnlist
    
    }
```

This call generates the following response:

```
_p_api_response: "{"_p_mins":5,"_p_price":"36703.73207769"}"
_p_mins: "5"
_p_price: "36703.73207769"
```

What I am trying to do is use the module 'json-to-bubble-object' as returned in the _p_api_response parameter (which is a test parameter and is not actually needed) to return the data. This makes my call dynamic so I don't have to manually specify the parameters for each different api call.

Hence, I am trying to make the API call look something like this:

```
var body = JSON.parse(response.body);

const {convert} = require('json-to-bubble-object');
    
let returnlist = []
returnlist.push(     JSON.stringify(convert(body))
 
 
)
 
    return {
        "result": returnlist
    
    }
```

but this returns null results

```
_p_api_response: null
_p_mins: null
_p_price: null
```

can someone let me know how I can return the data generated from the convert function as a list as done in the first request? Thanks

EDIT: For clarification, the *p* prefix allows the response headers to be viewed in the bubble.io builder, as seen in the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have enough reputation to comment but

I am unable to repro your problem.
You can view my repro here:

https://runkit.com/runkitname/so-a-nodejs

```js
const {convert} = require('json-to-bubble-object');

var body = {
    "mins": 5,
    "price": "34823.91104827"
}

body.api_response = JSON.stringify(convert(body))


let returnlist = []
returnlist.push(convert(body))

console.log({"result": returnlist})
```

console

```json
{
  result: [
    {
      _p_mins: 5,
      _p_price: '34823.91104827',
      _p_api_response: '{"_p_mins":5,"_p_price":"34823.91104827"}'
    }
  ]
}
```